# Current Record Calculated Field on Previous Record Calculated Value

Tags: sql-server

In this example, there are 5 periods of actual balances and the implied depreciation rates.  Starting in Period 6, need the Balance to be calculated on previous period balance ($8,177,480) * the current period depreciation rate (-1.50%) and so on.  I've heard recursive CTE but I am not familiar with them.

```
Period  DeprRate    Balance          Comment
1         0%        $10,000,000      Actual Values
2        -1.62%      $9,838,000      Actual Values
3        -7.41%      $9,109,004      Actual Values
4        -8.00%      $8,380,284      Actual Values
5        -2.42%      $8,177,481      Actual Values
6        -1.50%      null            should be $8,177,481*(1-.015)
7        -1.50%      null            should be Pd 6 Calc Balance *(1-.015)
8        -5.73%      null            should be Pd 7 Calc Balance *(1-.0573)
9        -4.13%      null            should be Pd 8 Calc Balance *(1-.0413)
10       -1.50%      null            should be Pd 9 Calc Balance *(1-.015)


CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Period] int, [DeprRate] float, Balance integer)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Period], [DeprRate], Balance)
VALUES
(1,0,10000000),
(2,-0.0162,9838000),
(3,-0.0741,9109004.2),
(4,-0.08,8380283.864),
(5,-0.0242,8177480.9944912),
(6,-0.015,null),
(7,-0.015,null),
(8,-0.0573,null),
(9,-0.0413,null),
(10,-0.015,null)
```

Comment: Could you post data **in text** so that no-one would have to type it into editor?

Comment: did you tried recursive CTE along with LAG, that might work.

Comment: Familiar with lag, not so much with recursive CTE.  Any example code for the above example to calculate each period's "future" balance (ie, periods 6-10)?

Answer (score 0):

"This seems relatively easy, but can't get it."

Yes, it is.  Did you follow these steps ?

"I have 10 periods of actual balances and the implied depreciation rates."
Step 1 : Create a table (Table_1) and populate it with these values.

" Starting in Period 11, need the Balance to be calculated on previous period balance * the current period depreciation rate."
Step 2 : Create a query for calculation of new rates based on the values of previous table, execute it and populate it to new table (Table_2).

" Period 11 isn't difficult if that's all that was needed by using lag. Problem is Period 12-20 need to be calculating current period balance on previous period calculated balance multiplied by the current period depreciation rate."
Step 3 : Two options here - one is through a recursive query as 'Vinit' commented.  Another option (easy) is to **repeat Step 2 and append to Table_2**.

=======

## Knowledge sharing / Value addition to your question : Depreciation is an Accounting concept, which usually taken into account either in the year end (closing of the books) or at the end of life of an asset.  This concept is very tricky as at least two (usually) different calculations may have to be performed to satisfy the tax compliance and also management accounting requirements.  Additional calculations may also have to be carried out for each type of asset, just to take decision to determine best possible option.

Though you did not include the date column in your sample data, you should be writing the script to calculate and populate the depreciated values based on a particular date.  You can also arrange to execute this script by specifying a trigger as well as through a job agent (scheduling).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks!  In your steps, how are you pulling in the previous period's calculated balance to use in the current period?